# How to move and rename multiple files using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a large number of files (>4 million) and need to rename and move them to another folder in small steps.

I am a total beginner in powershell, but I already managed to move them in small packages of 100 files (the powershell script is executed as scheduled task).

But so far I failed with renaming the files. In each file, there are two strings that need to be replaced. 
The following codes works fine, except for the renaming part (line 12 and 13):

```
#Get 'n' number of files
$FileLimit = 100 

$PickupDirectory = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\server\path$\ERROR\subfolder\"
$DropDirectory = "\\server\path$\destination\"

$Counter = 0
foreach ($file in $PickupDirectory)
{
    if ($Counter -ne $FileLimit)
    {
        $file | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '999999','367'}
        $file | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace 'oldname','newname'}

        $Destination = $DropDirectory+$file.Name

        Move-Item $file.FullName -destination $Destination
        $Counter++
    }  
}
exit
```

What is the correct way to rename those files?

Thank you so much for your help!
Best wishes
Philipp

Edit: Sorry, here's the Error Log :

```
Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\server\path$\ERROR\subfolder\1566392#5990762$20180116^999999_2018_01_16_oldname_1566392_Kägi.pdf' does not exist.
At C:\Scripts\mv_Verordnung_für_Physiotherapie.ps1:12 char:28
+ ... pDirectory | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '^999999','^367'}
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

Edit2: Updated the code with tipps from comments. Error still the same.

Comment: What isn't working with the renaming part?

Comment: Are you sure you want to replace `^999999` with `^367`? The first `^` is taken as "beginning of line", but the second one is taken literally. So `999999_myfile.txt` becomes `^367_myfile.txt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do the limiting (if necessary at all) earlier with the `Get-ChildItem` =>

```
$PickupDirectory = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\server\path$\ERROR\subfolder\" | Select -First $FileLimit
```

1. Instead of using the currently iterated item ($file) you use the whole array `$PickupDirectory`
2. You can't apply the 2. replace to an already changed value.
3. instead of rename and move do it in one step.

```
#Get 'n' number of files
$FileLimit = 100 

$PickupDirectory = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\server\path$\ERROR\subfolder\" | Select -First $FileLimit

$DropDirectory = "\\server\path$\destination\"

foreach ($file in $PickupDirectory){
    $Destination = Join-Path $DropDirectory ($file.Name -replace '^999999','^367' `
                                                        -replace 'oldname','newname')
    $file | Move-Item -Destination $Destination
}
```

Comment: Hi LotPings, thank you so much, now it works! Had to remove the "^" in the replace string, but thats ok.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `Rename-Item` on the `$PickupDirectory` collection. Instead call it on the `$file` variable you are using in the `foreach` loop:

```bsh
$file | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace '^999999', '^367' }
$file | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace 'oldname', 'newname' }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. Update my code, but I still get the error (see updated post above).